# How to match the first image element without preceding text?

Tags: php, html, regex

I need to select the the first image tag in a HTML string, but only if it does not have preceding text. So for example, it should match this:

```
<p><span><a href=""><img src="some.jpg"></a></span></p>
```

But it should not match this:

```
<p>Text text text<span><a href=""><img src="some.jpg"></a></span></p>
```

nor this:

```
<p><span>Text text text<a href=""><img src="some.jpg"></a></span></p>
```

I've tryed something like:

```
/(<[^>]+>)<img/is
```

So that I can select the tags before the img tag, but I'm not able to exclude the text that can be in any tag preceding the img element.

Some thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex solution:

```
$regex='#^(<[^>]+>)*<img#i';
var_dump(preg_match($regex,'<p><span><a href=""><img src="some.jpg"></a></span></p>'));
var_dump(preg_match($regex,'<p>Text text text<span><a href=""><img src="some.jpg"></a></span></p>'));
var_dump(preg_match($regex,'<p><span>Text text text<a href=""><img src="some.jpg"></a></span></p>'));
```

Outputs:

```
int(1)
int(0)
int(0)
```

[Live demo](http://3v4l.org/9XD8I)

<strike>**Edit**:</strike>

DOM/XPath solution:

```
foreach(array('<p><span><a href=""><img src="some.jpg"></a></span></p>',
'<p>Text text text<span><a href=""><img src="some.jpg"></a></span></p>',
'<p><span>Text text text<a href=""><img src="some.jpg"></a></span></p>') as $html)
{
    $dom=new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath=new DOMXPath($dom);
    var_dump($xpath->query('//img[string-length(//text())<=0]')->length);
}
```

Also outputs `1,0,0`.

[Live demo](http://3v4l.org/Danpg)

**Edit** #2: The XPath solution still works, but it also eliminated the situation that text come after `<img>`. Since the question hinted that "preceding" means *literally*, I think Regex is a better tool here.

Answer (score 0):

May be like this

```
$str = '
<p><span><a href=""><img src="some1.jpg"></a></span></p>
<p><span>Text text text<a href=""><img src="some2.jpg"></a></span></p>
<p><span>Text text text<a href=""><img src="some3.jpg"></a></span></p>
<p><span><a href=""><img src="some4.jpg"></a></span></p>';

preg_match_all('#<p>\s*<span>\s*<a.*(<img[^>]+>)#U', $str, $match);

echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars(print_r($match, 1)) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = strip_tags($yourContent, '<p><img>');
preg_match_all("#<p>(<img[^>]+>)#U", $content, $out);
print_r($out);
```